# Stripe form Issue in woocommerce checkout page fields are not displaying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have issue in my site on checkout page no stripe elements are shown in form [image]

Comment: it may be your plugin not loaded JS and CSS file

Comment: have you set the checkout page from admin?

Comment: yes i have added the checkout page from admin

Comment: check console have you find errors?

Comment: Do you have SSL enabled on your website?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with your jquery.min so try to remove the below link it will surely work for you
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js